# Is it feasible to use gunicorn in replace of tornado httpserver?

Tags: tornado, wsgi, gunicorn

I use tornado in my project with high-concurrency,Can I use gunicorn replace tornado httpserver and whether if it work more effective?

Comment: Depends on what you application does and what current request throughput and response times are? Also, are you using async APIs of Tornado, or using it to host a WSGI application? For WSGI applications, if using backend services Tornado isn't actually a good choice for WSGI as can only handle one request at a time when run it as single process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application is WSGI-based, then `gunicorn` is *much better* than Tornado's HTTPServer. Tornado [does not support concurrency for WSGI applications](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/wsgi.html#tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer)

If your application is a native Tornado application, then you can use `gunicorn` with the `--worker-class=tornado` option to serve your application. The concurrency and performance of this configuration will be the same as using Tornado alone (it is a wrapper around Tornado's HTTPServer). The advantage of using `gunicorn` in this case is that you would be able to monitor, configure, and manage your server using `gunicorn`'s interfaces and tools.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,my application is a native Tornado application.It is seems that there is no necessary to run my tornado apps on gunicorn WSGI.